# Unable to export Magento database using Xampp PhpMyAdmin due to too many input fields that exceed PHP max_input_vars

Tags: database, magento, phpmyadmin

While exporting Magento database from xampp (using PhpMyAdmin).I am getting error `.sql` file. and also getting a warning message during export start.

> Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields.  On submission, some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's `max_input_vars` configuration.

[image]

How can export a Magento database when I'm getting an error like this?

Magento version : Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export from command line if you have having issues with exporting from phpMyAdmin.

> backup/export: `# mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql`
>
> restore: `# mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql`

[Similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923150/exporting-mysql-database-from-xampp)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to php.ini file,

```
max_input_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
```